# How to add a callback function in the action call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am totally new to the `react-redux`. here I am using `thunk`. Now,
I have a following scenario where,

```
this.props.removeTech({ newArr, removeType });
```

I call this action from my component,

```
export function removeTech(data) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: REMOVE_TECH,
            data: data,
        });
    }
}
```

and it updates the state,

But

I am doing,

```
this.props.removeTech({ newArr, removeType });
    let validateData = this.validate(removeType, noc);
    console.log("removing data",validateData);
    this.setState({
      showError: validateData
    })
```

So the validateData needs some data that should be updated one, but it gets the previous data and because of that its not returning the proper value. So,

What I want is I want to call that function after the update of state. So, can any one help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

If `validate` is an asynchronous function, use a `Promise` and call `setState` in a `then`.
If `validate` is another action, maybe it's his job to update `showError` in state.

And for your information, you don't need thunk for removeTech, you can simply do :

`export const removeTech = data => ({
  type: REMOVE_TECH,
  data,
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can return a promise on your action `removeTech` and then you can use the `then()` method on `this.props.removeTech`.

Something like this:

```
export function removeTech(data) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: REMOVE_TECH,
            data: data,
        });
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
}
```

And then

```
this.props.removeTech({ newArr, removeType }).then(() => {
    let validateData = this.validate(removeType, noc);
    console.log("removing data",validateData);
    this.setState({
      showError: validateData
    })
});
```

Hope this helps :)